# Disable silent and verysilent uninstall in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to disable silent and verysilent uninstall in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't disable it directly, but you can check if it's running in silent mode and display a message/exit during the `InitializeSetup()`/`InitialiseUninstall()` event functions.

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  // Default to OK
  result := true;

  // If it's in silent mode, exit
  if WizardSilent() then
  begin
    MsgBox('This setup doesn''t support silent installations.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    result := false;
  end;
end;
```

Or for uninstall:

```
function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
begin
  // Default to OK
  result := true;

  // If it's in silent mode, exit
  if UninstallSilent() then
  begin
    MsgBox('This setup doesn''t support silent uninstallation.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    result := false;
  end;
end;
```

(Untested air code)

If you want to silently (??? :o) rerun the setup again in non silent mode, you can use this inside the `InitializeSetup` if block:

```
ShellExecAsOriginalUser('', ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'), '', '',  SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, 0);
```

Note that this will also drop any other parameters passed and prompt for elevation again.

Comment: You are missing the `Exit;` after when you set the `Result` to False to interrupt the installer. But wouldn't be better to execute the setup executable from `ExpandConstant('{srcexe}')` without `/SILENT` parameter (don't know if it's possible) ? +1 in the meantime..

Comment: @TLama: Oopos, I've adjusted to have a better default, this may be easier depending on what else needs to go into that function. As for re running `{srcexe}`, `[Code]` runs in the elevated part of the setup so the new non silent one will also be elevated, breaking the `...asoriginaluser` functionality.

Comment: @TLama: I'm talking rubbish, it can just use the `ExecAsOriginalUser()` function :o)

Comment: I want to disable silent uninstall, not install. I tried to call `WizardSilent()` in `InitializeUninstall()` function but I got the following message:
`Cannot call WIZARDSILENT function during Uninstall`

Comment: @Deanna: the code:
`function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
begin
    if WizardSilent() then begin
        MsgBox('...', mbError, MB_OK);
        result := false;
    end;
end;`

Comment: Then use `UninstallSilent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can use parameter like "/SP-, /SILENT, /VERYSILENT", So that every wizard page will disable or hidden. In  innosetup  click "Tool"-->"Parameter" and save the above parameters and build the application and run your test. Mostly this will help you for upload in microsoft app store. You can use the parameter in microsoft app store silent install parameters.