# How to rerun inno setup silent install in nonsilent mode

Tags: inno-setup, silent-installer

we can detect it - [Disable silent and verysilent uninstall in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815873/disable-silent-and-verysilent-)
uninstall-in-inno-setup and try to rerun with

```
ExecAsOriginalUser(ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, 0);
```

But it does not run anything in this case. Any ideas how to rerun installer in normal mode when silent install detected?

Comment: That was my blind, untested proposal which doesn't work (Deanna has a note about it as well). `Exec` as well as `ExecAsOriginalUser` returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` error code, when you attempt to run the setup binary from code, and I would suggest to make a temporary batch file and run the setup from there. Although, I'm not sure if you can run an executable from a batch file with the same privileges as the batch invoker.

Comment: I've just corrected my original answer to use `ShellExecAsOriginalUser()` that should elevate properly (still untested). I recomend deleting this question if it now works or I'll close as a duplicate.